# Em makes font too big in browser

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, frontend

I'm somewhat new to front-end web development and I'm having a bit of trouble with font sizes using em; I've learned a good deal by searching through this site, but still have some issues.

I'm using media queries to code a responsive site. When I specify my navigation text font size in ems so that it looks good on a mobile phone, it looks huge when I view it in a desktop browser. I set the body font size to 62.5% and my understanding is that ems are relative to that.

Any thoughts?

Update: Thanks Jackie! My problem was definitely that I wasn't thinking clearly about how ems will behave in child elements.

Comment: Do you have the viewport meta tag in the head of the document?

Comment: Show your code and explain what you are really trying to do. And `em` is (for font size) the font size of the parent element (which may or may not be the `body` element).

Answer (score 0):

Em's also look at relative space so whatever em values are set to your parent, it is going to trickle down to your child. The challenge to using em is that you must know (and remember) the parent size because it is the basis for how the rest of the type will behave. I would suggest using REM's as they are more true to the root.

In the example below, the parent is going to take into account your body font size to 62.5%, then increment accordingly, then the child will look at the parent for it's actual font size.

```
<style>
  .parent { font-size:1.5em }
  .child {  font-size:1em }
</style>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Text</div>
</div>
```